# failed erc20 gasless permit

Tags: permit

I apologize for reaching out, but as a newcomer to blockchain development, I've invested considerable time without finding a solution to my current challenge.

I am working on a task that involves generating distinct wallet addresses, monitoring them for incoming ERC20 transfers, and subsequently transferring the received funds from those wallets to a designated main wallet. To execute the transfer, I need to pre-fund the generated wallets with ETH to cover the gas fees, leading to a double gas payment.

Upon my research, I came across ERC20 permit, which allows gasless approval. Although gas fees are still involved, they can be handled by a relayer (main wallet). This approach appears to streamline the process and reduce the need for double gas payments.

Using metamask sign I signed following message

```
{
    "types": {
        "EIP712Domain": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "version",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "chainId",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "verifyingContract",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "Permit": [
            {
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "spender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "value",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "nonce",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ]
    },
    "primaryType": "Permit",
    "domain": {
        "name": "Liquid staked Ether 2.0",
        "version": "1",
        "chainId": "0x1",
        "verifyingContract": "0xae7ab96520de3a18e5e111b5eaab095312d7fe84"
    },
    "message": {
        "owner": "0xf77d26e37350e21a299d6afead2f2ab202db0008",
        "spender": "0x7f735420671313a069870685b13a1d5a26E09962",
        "value": "1158472395435294898592384258348512586931256000000000000000000",
        "nonce": 119,
        "deadline": 1767720003
    }
}
```

Then I tried to execute permit method from main wallet
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0fd889e9c630f13cb3a888660c6590c996ccc2de06720153fa0ef19f8fa1d9af

and transaction failed with unknown reason.

Any guidance or insights you can provide on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.